# First show the object that is equal to the incoming variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an object that looks like the example below. I want the object that is equal to the id in the variable to be sorted first. How can I do that?

```
const id = 15;
const obje = [
  {
    "name": "Join",
    "phone": "1234",
    "email": "test@mysite.com",
    "id": "12"
  },
  {
    "name": "Join2",
    "phone": "4321",
    "email": "test2@mysite.com",
    "id": "15"
  }
]
```

What I want to do is to rank the object equal to the id in the variable to the top.

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value). What have you tried already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of sorting find the index of the object where its id matches the search id, then [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) it out, and then add it to the start of the array with [`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift). You are mutating the array but it's quick, and without knowing the complete structure of your array, probably the easiest approach.

```js
const id=15,arr=[{name:"Join",phone:"1234",email:"test@mysite.com",id:"12"},{name:"Join2",phone:"4321",email:"test2@mysite.com",id:"15"}];

const index = arr.findIndex(obj => obj.id === id);
arr.unshift(arr.splice(index, 1)[0]);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Why does it add square brackets to the object it moves up?

Comment: @meridyen, sorry that was an error on my part. `splice` returns an array. You just need to take the first element from that. I've fixed the code in the answer.